# Query to get multiple results from single query or return null

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a **Holiday** table with following fields

```
COLUMN_NAME         DATA_TYPE
-------------------------------
HOLIDAY_ID          NUMBER(10,0)
HOLIDAY_NAME        VARCHAR2(150 BYTE)
HOLIDAY_DATE        TIMESTAMP(6)
DAY_OF_WEEK         VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
HOLIDAY_TYPE_ID     NUMBER
```

and the sample data is

```
HOLIDAY_ID   HOLIDAY_NAME     HOLIDAY_DATE                      DAY_OF_WEEK     HOLIDAY_TYPE_ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
305         Republic Day      26-01-17 12:00:00.000000000 AM    Thursday         1

306         Maha Shivratri    24-02-17 12:00:00.000000000 AM     Friday          1
```

I have used the following query to get the holiday_date of a particular month/year:
***(QUERY)***

```
select nvl((select to_char(holiday_date,'DD/MM/YY') holiday 
from admin_holiday where to_char(holiday_date,'DD-MON-YYYY') like '%-JUN-2016%' 
and holiday_type_id=1 and to_char(holiday_date,'Day') not like 'Sun%' 
and to_char(holiday_date,'Day') not like 'Sat%'),'0') holiday from dual
```

This works fine if the result is null(i.e for month/year= JUN/2016) but gives "single-row subquery returns more than one row" error when the month contains more than one holiday (i.e for month/year= OCT/2016)

How do I write a query such that if the query returns multiple rows then display those results else display '0' for NULL result?

[**NOTE** : The holidays are as per the Indian calendar]

Answer (score 0):

You should consider changing your query to this:

```
SELECT NVL(TO_CHAR(holiday_date,'DD/MM/YY'), '0') holiday
FROM admin_holiday 
WHERE TO_CHAR(holiday_date,'MON-YYYY') = 'JUN-2016' 
--WHERE TO_CHAR(holiday_date,'yyyymm') = '201606'
    AND holiday_type_id = 1 
    AND TO_CHAR(holiday_date,'Day') NOT IN ('Sun', 'Sat');
```

Comment: This query works fine in case of not null results but displays nothing for null result

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the nvl function to the column, to to the result, like this:

```
select nvl(to_char(holiday_date,'DD/MM/YY'),'0') holiday 
from (select 1 as dummy from dual) d left join admin_holiday 
on to_char(holiday_date,'DD-MON-YYYY') like '%-JUN-2016%' 
and holiday_type_id=1 and to_char(holiday_date,'Day') not like 'Sun%' 
and to_char(holiday_date,'Day') not like 'Sat%'
```

On a side note: learn how to write [sargable queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)

Comment: but in case of there is no data in table it will not return any data but i she required at least one record.

Comment: I tried this once but is returns nothing in case it is null and not '0'

Comment: @VikramSingh When you said `NULL`, did you mean `admin_holiday` have no record from your WHERE statement?

Comment: Yes it means admin_holiday has no record

Comment: OK, try this trick with the `dual`. I am not sure it will work, I have not tested it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NVL(TO_CHAR(holiday_date,'DD/MM/YY'), '0') holiday
FROM admin_holiday 
WHERE TO_CHAR(holiday_date,'MON-YYYY') = 'JUN-2016' 
--WHERE TO_CHAR(holiday_date,'yyyymm') = '201606'
    AND holiday_type_id = 1 
    AND TO_CHAR(holiday_date,'Day') NOT IN ('Sun', 'Sat')
union all
select '0' from dual where not exists(SELECT NVL(TO_CHAR(holiday_date,'DD/MM/YY'), '0') holiday
FROM admin_holiday 
WHERE TO_CHAR(holiday_date,'MON-YYYY') = 'JUN-2016' 
--WHERE TO_CHAR(holiday_date,'yyyymm') = '201606'
    AND holiday_type_id = 1 
    AND TO_CHAR(holiday_date,'Day') NOT IN ('Sun', 'Sat'))
```

Comment: No, this gives the error as "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: check now there was spell mistake.